# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04, Win 10: Ubuntu now suddenly freezes the moment I log in, how to reinstall Ubuntu only?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, freeze, reinstall

There are really 2 problems here, but at this point, I just want a clean re-install of the Ubuntu partition.

I used the same laptop with Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04 for several years with no issue. Then I step-wise updated through the LTS versions to arrive at 20.04 a while ago. Initially, it worked fine, but at some point, I probably screwed something up. The result is that the moment I log in into Ubuntu, the screen freezes up completely (no cursor movement, no reaction to keyboard input, no way to get the terminal up).

Every once in a while it is still functional, and I went through all tutorials on how to fix graphics card issues etc. as this seems to be the most likely culprit. Nothing helped. I managed to save all my Ubuntu data.
Now all I want is to safely do a clean re-install of the Ubuntu partition without messing up Windows. How do I do that?

I see various partitions on Windows in Disk Management (including the "primary partition", which seems large enough to be Ubuntu) but am unsure how to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this description to solve my problem: https://itsfoss.com/reinstall-ubuntu/

Fortunately, the already used Ubuntu partition was recognized during the install and my freezing issue went away once the clean install was complete. I did not have the option to repair my current install (probably because I opted for an update to 22.04 instead of reinstalling 20.04).

Be aware: R Studio currently seems to have issues with Ubuntu 22.04 for some reason.